# How to model a long race track in netlogo world

Tags: netlogo

How can I create a race track with resolution about 60 units wide and 4000 units long (for up to 20 agents)?
Note: during any simulation, the focus/zoom may be only where the agents are located along the track.

Racetrack shape example: 
http://www.offtrackbetting.com/images/racetracks/OP/oaklawn_park_tl.gif

Any useful link or example would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: So the question is not how to draw the whole racetrack, but more a problem of wanting to be able to have the track redrawn to just show a section where the majority/leaders or whatever are? If so, you are going to have to create a draw-track function that is called whenever you need a new track section and you will need to think about how to make the cars appear to move if you are also moving the racetrack. In the meantime, there are some traffic models in the model library that might be useful.

Comment: There is a "zoom" functionality in NetLogo, but you have to use 3D view. Try this, for example: Open **Traffic Grid** model, click **Setup**, type `follow turtle 0`, click **Go** button and click **3D** button on top-right of the view window.

Comment: Another way to get zooming is described at https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Multiple-views-via-HubNet

Comment: Yes that's right, I am more interested to have a view (zoom) of the location where all agents are a a given point in time. Just need to confirm an efficient method to draw / redraw each view and have the agents move seamlessly from one part (view) of the track to another.